# Under GDPR can a company give out the demographics of employees e.g. ethnic background without anonymising it?

Tags: gdpr, data-protection, personal-information

If a client asks for the demographics of a company's employees e.g. female to male ratio or ethnicity. Does this have to be anonymised so it is compliant with the GDPR or can the names be revealed?

Answer (score 2):

In principle, the company can disclose personal data as long as it has a legal basis such as a legitimate interest to do so. This legitimate interest must outweigh the interests, rights, and freedoms of the affected persons.

But in this particular scenario I have doubts on two grounds.

First, the company might not have a sufficiently compelling legitimate interest. It's none of the client's business what a particular employee's demographics are. Even if the company has a legitimate interest, it can only process data as necessary for that purpose – but no more. For example, if the legitimate interest can be satisfied with aggregate statistics, then there is no legal basis for disclosing per-employee information.

Second, and more importantly, some of this information may fall under “special categories” of data in the sense of [Art 9 GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-9-gdpr/). Such special categories are illegal to process, unless an explicit exception applies. Processing information about the “racial or ethnic origin” is explicitly illegal, though it may e.g. be permissible if explicitly authorized by national laws. Processing information about gender is not explicitly prohibited, though there might be interesting edge cases. For example, an employer would almost certainly fail to have a legitimate interest for a processing activity that would out a trans employee.

So a company should think about:

1. whether it is allowed to process the data in the first place, taking into account Art 9 GDPR
2. if so, whether it has a legal basis for processing (such as a sufficient legitimate interest)
3. if so, and if the information is taken from existing records, whether it is allowed to reuse the data for a different purpose than it was collected for (see Art 6(4) GDPR)
4. if so, what the minimum necessary amount of data for this purpose would be

Likely, this means sharing no data at all (because the data may not be collected or reused in the first place), or only sharing aggregate statistics.

Of course, there can be reasonable scenarios where processing this kind of data is appropriate, for example in a modelling agency. But taking into account Art 9 GDPR, this might require explicit consent if national laws do not provide a suitable exception.

Comment: "*because the data may not be collected or reused in the first place*" Are you suggesting that  the internal personnel records of a company may not lawfully record the sex or ethnicity of individual employees? Has there been any ruling or even any claim to that effect? Whether such information may be **disclosed** is different.  US companies are often required by law to record this info, to monitor anti-discrimination efforts; I don't know if that is ever true in the EU.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Some (but not all) European countries have laws that ask employers to report statistics on ethnic diversity. An employer would then be allowed to follow this law, but wouldn't be allowed to use the information about ethnic origin for any different purpose. This follows directly from Art 9 GDPR. Information about gender is not restricted like this, and is also needed for correct form of address in some languages. In contrast to legal or social gender, I would argue that information about sex is health data and thus restricted under Art 9 as well.

Comment: So does that mean that the company cannot share the information if it is for a diversity/inclusion programme or for a client who wants to use the company's services but would first like to know about their diversity processes? Could this sort of situation be classed as a legitimate interest?

Comment: @Kin: " Legitimate interest" is often misunderstood. It is not a "I get to ignore GDPR because I want to" exception.

Comment: @Kin If the data involves “special categories”, then a legitimate interest is not sufficient. And in any case, I doubt that there would be a legitimate interest for disclosing individual demographics about employees. It sounds to me like aggregate, anonymized statistics would be sufficient for such diversity programs. But I think there's a good chance that there would be a legitimate interest for compiling statistics on gender. Statistics on ethnic origin would require the employee's consent though.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful comments.